# change from mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wrote code that allow me to get information from mysql using mysql which is old code, and i tried to change to mysqli from mysql but some how is not working right, I believe that i'm still new to learn about mysqli, can any one help me to to write into mysqli from mysql so i can learn myself from there please... here is code...

thanks...

```
<?php
include('db.php');
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['kw']) && $_POST['kw'] != '')
{
  $kws = $_POST['kw'];
  $kws = mysql_real_escape_string($kws); 
  $query = "select * from product where product_name like '%".$kws."%' limit 10" ;
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  $count = mysql_num_rows($res);
  $i = 0;

  if($count > 0)
  {
    echo "<ul>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
      echo "<a href='$row[product_name]'><li>";
      echo "<div id='rest'>";
      echo $row['product_name'];
      echo "<br />";
      echo "<td>";?><img src="<?php echo $row["screenshot"];?>" height="100" width="100" <?php echo "</td>" ; 
      echo "</div>";
      echo "<div style='clear:both;'></div></li></a>";
      $i++;
      if($i == 5) break;
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    if($count > 5)
    {
      echo "<div id='view_more'><a href='#'>View more results</a></div>";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<div id='no_result'>No result found !</div>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Its almost the same.  Just look up mysqli functions that are the same as the mysql ones and see that they require a link parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The general rule of thumb is:

## Do not change.

But write mysqli version from scratch.

As your approach with old mysql ext were all wrong, do not translate it to new mysqli. Just learn mysqli and then write the whole thing from scratch.

Otherwise you'd better leave your old code as is, just because such a mechanical rewriting will do not a slightest good.

Comment: yes i understand that, please correct me if i'm wrong, if i leave that old there, and not change to mysqli, what happen to the hosting company in the future, does does new version of php are prepare not going to accept mysql in the future because they prepare to change to mysqli as default! is this correct!

Comment: there is no "default" driver. you can use whatever you wish

Comment: @andy However, the best choice would be to get yourself whatever helper library, and make use of **placeholders**